# Reusing a disk which was in the RAID array

Tags: centos7, raid1

My DC has added a new hard disk. It appears as md124 inactive sdc1. When I try to mount, the error is unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member',

I need to use this disk for backup VM. Can I just do a `fdisk /dev/sdc1`?
Or I do have to break the raid array?

```
#Break the array, removing the mirror
mdadm --manage /dev/md124 --fail /dev/sdc1
mdadm --manage /dev/md124 --remove /dev/sdc1
#Create a new file system on the mirror
mke2fs -t ext4 -j /dev/sdc1
#Mount the mirror so you can use it
mkdir /mnt/backup
mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/backup


[root@~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md124 : inactive sdc1[0](S)
      976628736 blocks super 1.2

md128 : active raid1 sdb4[1] sda4[0]
      919444160 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/7 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md125 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      524288 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md126 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      52427776 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 1/1 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

md127 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      4193280 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: You say that after `mke2fs`, the `mount` command doesn't work? One thing I don't understand: After removing sdc1 from the array, it is still in the array. Also, I don't know what you want to achieve with `fdisk`. Normally, you don't run `fdisk` on a partition; you only run it on disks, such as /dev/sdc.

Answer (score 0):

That's because failing and removing a device from RAID set doesn't say it is no more RAID. It just says the rest of RAID set they don't want this device anymore.

To disband a RAID disk completely:

1. Stop md124:

   ```
   mdadm --stop /dev/md124
   ```
2. **Remove MD RAID metadata labels from disk**:

   ```
   mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdc1
   ```
3. (Optional) change partition type:

   ```
   fdisk /dev/sdc
   t
   (select parition 1 to be type 83, or in case of GPT type 20)
   w
   ```

Now you may create a file system and use a disk without RAID.

Comment: I executed below commands:


mdadm --manage --stop /dev/md124



wipefs -a /dev/sdc1

mke2fs -t ext4 -j /dev/sdc1

Comment: `wipefs` also could be used for that, but I prefer managing MD RAID labels with dedicated `mdadm` tool. Essentially you've done the same thing. There also is a "brute force" approach, to fill entire device (sdc1 or even sdc) with zeros.